# Access Form : import picture from SharePoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-2013

The tables of my database are stored in SharePoint lists. But the front-end (forms) is still in Ms Access, with linked tables to SharePoint.

I would like to add a picture in my form but SharePoint would not import a column with "Picture" type and I don't know which path I should write in the Access Form, as the pictures are on SharePoint and not on my computer...

Does somebody know how I can add these pictures in the form ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Images or files in SharePoint can be accessed using the WebDav (if webdav protocol enabled) with full path \\yourserver\yoursite\library\image.ext".

I am not too familiar with Access, but from what I can think of on top of my head, you can

1. create a column named Picture in Access table and populate it with the paths to the images stored in SharePoint like above.
2. in the form (design view), insert an image control from design tab, then specify the Picture column as the control source (right-click on image box> Properties > Data tab > Control Source)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But when I try to put the column picture in the  control source, nothing is displayed... As if Access cannot load a picture from a website...